# Core Bluetooth and applicationWillTerminate:

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Using Core Bluetooth, two iOS devices have to stay connected to each other (as peripheral and central at the same time) even when the app is in the background. When the user closes the app from the multitasking bar (or the app is killed by the system), I need the devices to cancel the connections to each other (otherwise the bluetooth icon stays white and problems occur...) I see that `applicationWillTerminate:` isn't called. Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS manages the Bluetooth connections of your app, and will disconnect by itself when your app gets killed and no other app is using the same shared Bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 0):

Any application that doesn't have `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` set in their `Info.plist` will never have `applicationWillTerminate:` called. ([Apple documentation on `applicationWillTerminate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) and [on `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23)).

You'll need to find another way to clean up your connections.